# R - data table rolling window- customized function

Tags: r, apply, zoo

I need to calculate for a ts if the value that I'm working with is an outlier coinsidering the previous 30 values.
The data that I'm working with has a dimension of 600 columns by 200000 rows. So I want to use the benefits of data table speed.

My function is:

```
es_outlier<-function(vect){
  qq =quantile(vect, prob=c(0.25,0.75), na.rm=T)
  q3=qq[2]
  IC=q3-qq[1]
  limSup=q3+IC*1.5
  vector_final=abs(vect)>limSup
  return(vector_final[length(vect)] )
}
```

An example table would be:

```
library(data.table)

dt<-data.table(x1=runif(50000), x2=runif(50000))
dt$x1[555]<-2000
dt$x2[556]<-2000
```

I can solve this with zoo package:

```
zoo::rollapply(dt,30,es_outlier, fill=NA,align='right')
```

But it takes a lot fo time and it is less than my real data.

I would like something like:

```
dt[, (nom):=lapply(.SD,function, n=30)]
```

I tried using Rcpp but it doesn't have a quantile function.

Is there a faster way to apply my function?

PS: for a tiny table the function returns:

```
x<-data.frame(x1=1:8, x2=c(1:7,2000))
x_dt<-data.table(x)
zoo::rollapply(x_dt,5,es_outlier, fill=NA,align='right')

 x1    x2
 NA    NA
 NA    NA
 NA    NA
 NA    NA
 FALSE FALSE
 FALSE FALSE
 FALSE FALSE
 FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: can you replicate your rows and assign groups, ie, g1=1:30, g2=2:31, etc, then do `es_outlier` by group in data table?

Comment: @rawr, I guess... does it take less time? I'm new in data table so I'm not sure how to write that.

Comment: I'm not sure, you have a few bottlenecks: your function, the size of the data, and rollapply. data table is supposed to mitigate the size up to millions of rows, and the function is not changing, so it seems like you can eliminate one bottleneck in rollapply if you stack the data?

Comment: also you can get a slight speed increase in your function by only calling `quantile` once (and you don't use the median so you can get rid of that, too) `eso2 <- function(v) {x <- quantile(v, c(.25, .75), na.rm = TRUE); l <- x[2L] + (x[2L] - x[1L]) * 1.5; (abs(v) > l)[length(v)]}`

Comment: @rawr, thanks for the median advice, but still need another improvement

Comment: Profile your code and check whether most of the time is taken in `es_outlier`. If it is then wrapping it in something else such as data.table won't help.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck. the result starts with:                                       
 total.time total.pct self.time self.pct
"coredata"               14.32    100.00      0.00     0.00
"rollapply"              14.32    100.00      0.00     0.00
"rollapply.default"      14.32    100.00      0.00     0.00
"zoo::rollapply"         14.32    100.00      0.00     0.00
"rollapply.zoo"          14.30     99.86      0.02     0.14
"do.call"                14.28     99.72      0.00     0.00

Comment: My comment was to check whether most of the time is taken in `es_outlier` or not.  The snippet you have shown does not show this.

Comment: As this has nothing to do with Rcpp I will remove the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest to store the sorted vector so that when moving from window to window, just need add 1 new element. Still not a great speedup though..

```
set.seed(25L)
N <- 50000
dt <- data.frame(x1=runif(N), x2=runif(N))
dt$x1[555] <- 2000
dt$x2[556] <- 2000
wl <- 30

####################################################################################################
#' Calculate IQR for a sorted vector with 30 observations
#' 
#' @details assume that sorted is sorted. using type 7 in ?quantile.
#' 
#' @param sorted sorted numeric vector
#' 
#' @return the interquartile range
#' 
iqr30obs <- function(sorted) {
    c(sorted[8] + 0.25 * (sorted[9] - sorted[8]), sorted[22] + 0.75 * (sorted[23] - sorted[22]))
} #iqr30obs


es_outlier2 <- function(vect) {
    start <- 1
    end <- start + wl - 1
    sorted <- sort(structure(vect[start:end], names=start:end))
    i <- 0
    res <- rep(NA, nrow(dt))
    while (end < nrow(dt)) {  
        locFirstObs <- which(names(sorted)==start)

        if (!(i > 9 && i < 22 && locFirstObs > 9 && locFirstObs < 22)) {
            #changes in the 8th. 9th, 22th and 23th positions after removing first obs 
            #and adding new observation            
            qt <- iqr30obs(sorted)
            iqr1.5 <- 1.5 * (qt[2] - qt[1])
        }
        res[end] <- sorted[as.character(end)] < qt[1] - iqr1.5 |
               sorted[as.character(end)] > qt[2] + iqr1.5

        #moving to next window ----
        #remove the first observation in the window
        sorted <- sorted[-locFirstObs]

        #create the new observation to add to window
        toAdd <- structure(vect[end+1], names=end+1)

        #insert this new observation into the sorted vector while maintaining order
        for (i in seq_along(sorted)) {
            if (toAdd < sorted[i]) {
                sorted <- c(sorted[seq_len(i-1)], toAdd, sorted[i:(wl-1)])
                break
            }
        }
        if (i == length(sorted)) {
            sorted <- c(sorted, toAdd)
        }

        #increment indices
        start <- start + 1
        end <- end + 1
    } #while

    res
} #es_outlier2

es_outlier<-function(vect){
    qq =quantile(vect, prob=c(0.25,0.75), na.rm=T)
    q3=qq[2]
    IC=q3-qq[1]
    limSup=q3+IC*1.5
    vector_final=abs(vect)>limSup
    return(vector_final[length(vect)] )
}
```

results:

```
system.time(es_outlier2(dt$x1))
# user  system elapsed 
# 4.62    0.00    4.67 
system.time(es_outlier2(dt$x2))
# user  system elapsed 
# 4.56    0.00    4.83 

system.time(zoo::rollapply(dt, 30, es_outlier, fill=NA, align='right'))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  17.59    0.01   17.69
```

Comment: Never *ever* post `rm(list=ls())`.

Comment: Quick question: why do you use 0.25 and 0.75 to get the values of Q1 and Q3 in c(sorted[8] + 0.25 * (sorted[9] - sorted[8]), sorted[22] + 0.75 * (sorted[23] - sorted[22])). I would do just the regular average.

Comment: for type = 7, the 25th quantile is a linear interpolation between the 8th ordered statistic and 9th order statistic of a sample with 30 observations. Similarly for 75th quantile. Or leveraging off computing, check out `quantile(1:30, c(0.25,0.75))`. Would regular average get you the same results? If you prefer another type, feel free to change the `iqr30obs` function